# Storage Access Framework - File saved empty (0 byte) on cloud locations (uri from picker called with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)

Tags: java, android, json, nextcloud, google-drive-picker

My Android app can save files on device disk by means of Storage Access Framework,
cannot save on cloud locations instead.

I am using the following code to open the file picker to save a file:

```
Intent intentCreate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intentCreate.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);             
intentCreate.setType("application/json");
intentCreate.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileNameGlobal + JSON_MY_FILE_EXT);
startActivityForResult(intentCreate, REQUEST_CODE);
```

(I checked on a Galaxy A10 with Android 11)

On my device I have GoogleDrive, NextCloud, Onedrive.

The picker shows the device disk, GoogleDrive, NextCloud, but does not show Onedrive.

I choose one and the actual uri of the newly created file is retrieved in onActivityResult() method, then used in

```
static public void writeNewTextDocumentInUri(final Activity activity, final Uri uri, final String mimetype, final String text) {

                                final ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
                                boolean result=true;
                                try {

                                    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
                                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
                                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                                    writer.write(text);//the same using the append method
                                    writer.flush();
                                    writer.close();
                                    result = true;

                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    result = false;

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    result = false;

                                }

                                if (!result) openDialog();

    }
```

(mimetype is application/json)

This code works if I choose to save on the device storage, but fails with GoogleDrive and NextCloud.

I get an empty file saved (0 bytes).

I try to read it with the following code:

```
static public String readTextDocument(Activity activity, String fileUri) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver;
        contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        InputStream is;

        try {
            is = contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

        if (is == null) return null;

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        String text = new String();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                text = text + line + "\n";

            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return null;
        }

        return text;
    }
```

This only works from the device storage.

If instead I try to read the empty file created on GoogleDrive I get IOException, that is catched, while on NextCloud I get a more complex exception in logcat output:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2395)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:781)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1993)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1808)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1485)
```

Why the files are saved empty and cannot be read?

Comment: Do not use ParcelFileDescriptor and FileOutputStream but OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

Comment: `Relevant app permissions are:` No. Those are not relevant. And not needed. Maybe only INTERNET for cloud drives.

Comment: And why did you post that FileProvider stuff? That serves nothing.

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` My god... `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is this your first day of Android internet programming?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags((Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION));` None of those flags are needed. They do nothing. And although they do not harm you better remove them as there is a chance that a first day Android programmer might read this and gets confused.

Comment: @blackapps Turn your comment into an answer, because it works, otherwise I will create one

Answer (score 0):

The working code is:

```
 final ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
                           
                            try {
                                OutputStream os = activity.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                                os.write(text.getBytes());
                                os.flush();
                                os.close();

                                result = true;
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                               

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              
                            }
```